# Chrome doesn't load SWF by flash builder

Tags: google-chrome, apache-flex, flash-builder, flash, flex4.6

I am using flash builder 4.7 premium build SWF. But chrome does not load and show. I have to change default browser to internet explorer to view my SWF. I have flash version 15.0.0.239 installed and I use flex 4.6.0 SDK. Chrome:plugins already set to enable flash both pepflashplayer.dll and NPSWF32_15_0_0_239.dll. Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't run both Flash player plugins at the same time. Disable one or the other.

Comment: something wrong pepperflash, I have it disabled and works now. thank you.